# get null column after join tables on this coulmn laravel

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

There are two **types** of destination one is **FLIGHT** and the other is **REGION**, and
if the type of the destination is **REGION** then the `flight_id` will be `null`

```
DB::table('destinations as d')
            ->join('flights as f','d.flight_id','=','f.flight_id')
            ->where('f.status','=','ACTIVE')
            ->whereNull(['d.deleted_at', 'f.deleted_at'])->paginate(20);
```

I need also to get `destinations` **where** `destinations.flight_id = null`,

with this join I can't because this join is on `flight_id`.

Comment: Could you share your db schema ?

Comment: I suggest to enable query logging and see what is the SQL query executed then try to execute the query directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I catch the problem

```
DB::table('destinations as d')
            ->select('d.*','f.flight_id as flightId','f.flight_number','f.departure','f.arrival','f.air_line','f.air_port','f.stops')
            ->leftJoin('flights as f','d.flight_id','=','f.flight_id')
            ->whereNull(['d.deleted_at', 'f.deleted_at'])
            ->paginate(20);
```

I should differ between the `destination.flight_id` and `flight.flight_id` because they are the same name by adding `select()`

but not this is the exact problem, the problem is with the join it must be **left join**
and this is some data that I get as an example:

```
}
      3 => {#500 ▼
        +"destination_id": 33
        +"name": "USA"
        +"flight_id": 3
        +"type": "FLIGHT"
        +"status": "ACTIVE"
        +"created_at": "2020-01-27 14:41:17"
        +"updated_at": "2020-01-27 14:41:17"
        +"deleted_at": null
        +"flightId": 3
        +"flight_number": "#A205"
        +"departure": "2020-01-27 01:00:00"
        +"arrival": "2020-01-31 01:00:00"
        +"air_line": "sss"
        +"air_port": "zzz"
        +"stops": 2
      }
      4 => {#1011 ▼
        +"destination_id": 34
        +"name": "BEA"
        +"flight_id": null
        +"type": "REGION"
        +"status": "ACTIVE"
        +"created_at": "2020-01-27 14:42:57"
        +"updated_at": "2020-01-27 14:42:57"
        +"deleted_at": null
        +"flightId": null
        +"flight_number": null
        +"departure": null
        +"arrival": null
        +"air_line": null
        +"air_port": null
        +"stops": null
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another condition to your query.

```
 DB::table('destinations as d')
            ->join('flights as f','d.flight_id','=','f.flight_id')
            ->where('f.status','=','ACTIVE')
            ->where('d.flight_id','=','NULL') // added
            ->whereNull(['d.deleted_at', 'f.deleted_at'])
            ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: @SohaibEl-Khatib you may need to modify the second where condition just try it out with different columns you need