# How to automatically filter foreign table's deleted_at = null while using join in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent, soft-delete

As it is right now ->join() is a query builder so it wouldn't using Model that has SoftDelete, there is too many codes that used join in my project so I don't want to manually replace it all with eager loading ->with(), anyone know how to do it while keeping the join?

For example I want to get a data like this without adding ->where('tb_b.deleted_at', null) to all my codes:

```
$data = TabelA::join('tb_b', 'tb_a.id_b', '=', 'tb_b.id_b')->get()
```

Comment: [Laravel Join on Null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68185008/2943403) and [get null column after join tables on this coulmn laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59936067/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways to solve this

1. By using a whereNull constraint

```
$data = TabelA::join('tb_b', 'tb_a.id_b', '=', 'tb_b.id_b')
    ->whereNull('tb_b.deleted_at')
    ->get();
```

2. Creating a global scope in your model (here, I will assume TbB Model). Add the following function in your model class to create a global scope to automatically filter your model get method.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('notDeleted', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('deleted_at', null);
    });
}
```

Then, you will do this when you need your data without the deleted data

```
$data = TabelA::withoutGlobalScope('notDeleted')
    ->join('tb_b', 'tb_a.id_b', '=', 'tb_b.id_b')
    ->get();
```

Read more on Laravel scope here: https://learn2torials.com/a/laravel8-global-model-scope

Comment: This one in particular ($foreign is an array of foreign table names): 
public function scopeNotDeleted($query, $foreign){
        $result = '';
        foreach ($foreign as $key => $value){
                $result .= $query->where($value.'deleted_at', null);
        }
        return $result
}

Comment: And then: $data = TabelA::join('tb_b', 'tb_a.id_b', '=', 'tb_b.id_b')->notDeleted(['tb_b'])->get()

Answer (score 0):

Three alternatives

1. Adding a WHERE clause after the join

```php
TabelA::query()
    ->join('tb_b', 'tb_a.id_b', '=', 'tb_b.id_b')
    ->whereNull('tb_b.deleted_at')
    ->get()
```

2. Adding an AND clause to the join

```php
TabelA::query()
    ->join(function ($join) {
        $join->on('tb_b', 'tb_a.id_b', '=', 'tb_b.id_b')
            ->whereNull('tb_b.deleted_at');
    })
    ->get()
```

3. Joining on a subquery.

```php
TabelA::query()
    ->joinSub(
        function ($sub) {
            $sub->from('tb_b')
                ->whereNull('tb_b.deleted_at');
        }),
        'tb_b_alias',
        'tb_b_alias.id_b',
        '=',
        'tb_a.id_b'
    )
    ->get()
```

Comment: Please vote to close new duplicates instead of answering them.  If you find an earlier instance of the same question and it doesn't contain your best advice, then please add a new answer on the older page.  When you answer duplicate questions, then the Roomba cannot do its important work.

Comment: With what?  Caring about Stack Overflow? [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: That is a lofty way of putting it, but duplicates are more often than not "similar questions". I care about Stack Overflow as a Q&A site. No more than that.

Comment: If all people shared your perspective and ignored opportunities to curate/consolidate content, then you'd find that your valuable insights would be less likely to be found by the people who truly need the insight (because all new questions would diminish the likelihood of your previous posts being found).  Your answer looks like you know what you are talking about.  This makes me wonder how many of your contributions have not been posted in the most ideal location for maximum impact/reach to the researchers that would directly benefit.